# Can I turn off my Battlefield 4 'Rent-a-server' and save my purchased 'days' this way?

Tags: xbox-one, battlefield-4

For Battlefield 4, you can rent servers to play on. Just to be clear, this is **not** any random server to rent, I am referring to the ['rent-a-server' from EA itself](https://help.ea.com/en-gb/help/battlefield/battlefield-4/battlefield-4-server-rental-info/) which is the only way to rent a server on Xbox according to my knowledge.

Prices variate between $0.80 to $1.50 a day.

I've noticed that sometimes, some of my favourite servers are missing. Is this because they are turned "off" somehow? If this is possible, will I be able to save days on my subscription counter this way?

I'm asking this because I enjoy to play on certain maps/gametypes but its hard to find these sometimes and a lot of servers have home rules that I dislike. I only play on weekends so I would like to have a server running on the weekends only.

I know I could just rent a server for 2-3 days at a price of $3-4.5
But if the answer to my question is true, then i could rent a server for almost half the price and run it for much longer.

Comment: This would depend on the company you're renting from, and their policies.

Comment: You'd probably have better luck with this question in someplace like http://superuser.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about renting servers, which has nothing to do with the actual game.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a server provider issue.

Comment: @Vemonus its not offtopic, its a game feature, consider it a more advanced feature then a custom game in say Halo. (see edit)

Comment: @dly its not offtopic, its a game feature, consider it a more advanced feature then a custom game in say Halo. (see edit)

Comment: You pre-pay for the days, so no turning off the server, won't save you days

Comment: @Ramhound thx, if you want to turn your comment into an answer, could you include some sort of source? even if its just personal experience.